# The right folder structure for many-to-many relations

Tags: node.js, typescript, architecture, nestjs, directory-structure

I follow the most common structure for nestjs where I have separate folder for each domain

```
src/
  user/
    controllers/
      user.controller.ts
    repositories/
      user.repository.ts
    services/
      user.service.ts
    user.module.ts
  team/
    // the same as above but for team entity
    team.module.ts
  app.module.ts
```

In my application, I have many-to-many relations between `user` and `team`. So, users can have many teams, as teams can have many users. For this purpose, I created table `user_teams` and an obvious separate repository for this table.
In most of places in my application I need to use functions like `getAllUsersInTeam(idTeam: number)` and `getAllTeamsBelongsToUser(idUser: number)` and I have implemented this functions in repository `UserTeamRepository`. My question is where the right place to keep this repository file? In which module? I have several ideas

1. Create a separate folder on the same level as the main domain entities

   ```
   src/
     user/
       // user module files
     team/
       // team module files
     user-team/
       repositories/
         user-team.repository.ts
       user-team.module.ts
   ```

   In this case, potentially I will have a lot of folders for each many-to-many relations which will bring confusing and messing in the project.
2. Keep `UserTeamRepository` in some of the modules `user` or `team`.

   ```
   src/
     user/
       repositories/
         user-team.repository.ts
     // or
     team/
       repositories/
         user-team.repository.ts
   ```

   In this case I see problem with understading of the project. Why we keep one relations in one folder, but other we decided to keep in another way. How to fast search these kind of relations. I think new developers will be confused where find needed relations and where to keep new relations, cuz in good arhitecture should be no questions where to keep new class.

I'm open to any discussions and thoughts. Thanks for feedback in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to me that you decided to have an `UserTeamRepository` at all.

If you want a method `getAllUsersInTeam`, it should be in `UserRepository` since you are requesting Users.
If you want a method `getAllTeamsBelongsToUser`, it should be in `TeamRepository` since you are requesting Teams.

Then, each of these methods is responsible to join on your middle table to accomplish its mission.

Comment: I don't want the User to know about some relations with Team. I want to divide it and manage it separately in an isolated way, without knowing about each other. So, one repository - one table. And if in my system will be a new entity that also will have many-to-many relation to User, my UserRepository must know about 3 tables at all. This is not good and these kinds of relations can grow and the system becomes unpredictable, cuz need to write business logic related to relations user-<any_entity> in two places instead of one. That's why it important to have one repository - one table.